# A metal cube with volume of 1000 cubic metres ... Use the differential to show that the volume of the cube is then increased by p%. Find p.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, optimization

A metal cube with volume of 1000 cubic metres is heated and the length of each
edge is thereby increased by 1%. Use the differential to show that the volume of
the cube is then increased by p%. Find p.

---

We know that since it is a cube, we can say:

$V(x)=x^3$.

$V=(x + 0.01x)^3$.

Then,

$d V = d(x + 0.01x)^3$

$d V = 3(x+0.01x)^2*(1+0.01) \text{   }dx$

$d V = 3(x+0.01x)^2*(1.01) \text{   }dx$

I've calculated the differential. Now is my question done? I don't really understand what it means by "Use the differential to show that the volume of the cube is then increased by p%. Find p."

Comment: The _length_ increases by $1\%$, which means that it goes from $x$ to $x+0.01x=(1+0.01)x$. You're asked to use differentiation to approximate $p$ such that the volume goes from $V$ to $(1+p)V$.

Comment: ${1.01^3 V - V \over V} = 3.0301\%$.  Note that the answer is independent of the initial volume $V$.

Comment: You're asked to find the increase in volume in percentage terms from a 1% increase in the length of each edge of the cube. What you've done is found in the increase in volume in absolute terms from a p% increase in the length of each edge of the cube. I don't think those two are the same thing.

Comment: David what did you rearrange for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what they want you to do (this use of notation is not for the purists out there; we will, in true physicist spirit, interpret $dx$ as "a small change in $x$"):

First of all, $dV = 3x^2\,dx$. We have $x = 10$ and $dx = x\cdot 0.01 = 0.1$. That makes $dV = 30$. Since $V$ started out at $1000$, and has increased by $30$ (to first order approximation), we see that the volume has increased by $p = 3\%$.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of problem, closely related to error propagation, logarithmic differentiation is useful $$V=x^3\implies \log(V)=3\log(x)\implies \frac{dV}V= 3\frac{dx}x\implies \frac{\Delta V}V= 3\frac{\Delta x}x$$